# Should I store password in cookie while creating a login form in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

What is the best way to store user login details without storing password in cookie? I have searched on google but couldn't find the expected answer as they all were storing the password in cookie which is not safe.

Comment: Why do you need to store the user's password in a cookie?

Comment: you can use session instead of cookie

Comment: Why not store it server-side...?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what do you mean by "store password in cookie", actually I can't think of scenario that request and response need to carry "password" in cookie.

Comment: I'm creating a login form with "Remember me" checkbox which should allow the user to login next time without filling the login form. I've read on google and watched videos on youtube where they were storing the username and password in cookie. on the other hand I also came to know that cookies store values as a plain text which is unsafe. Pls guide me

Comment: I've also read about "FormAuthentication Ticket", but i need a proper article on how to generate form authentication ticket in C#.

My 2nd ques is which is the best way to authenticate user login:cookie or formauthentication?

Comment: Don't roll your own authentication, it's a complex topic and getting it wrong has serious consequences. There are many built-in methods in .NET you can use already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you store login **status** in cookie. This is how:

1. Client sends username and password (usually over HTTPS);
2. Server receives and validates it;
3. If it is valid, server use `Set-Cookie` response header to send cookies from server to client;
4. If it is invalid, server may response error (401 unauthorized);
5. Client sends cookies containing login status information back to server with following requests.